# url not correctly shown in email template

Tags: php, html

I've got the following set up, the `$url` is taken from

`<td> <?php echo $row['url']?> </td>`

And a ping is done via `curl` which works fine (loading time is long but its aprox. 160 sites that are being pinged)

```
<?php
    $url = $row['url'];
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (200==$retcode) {
        echo "<td><span class='badge badge-success'>LIVE</span></td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td><span class='badge badge-danger'>DOWN</span></td>";
        $path_to_file = './emailtemplate.html';
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
        $file_contents = str_replace("depplaceholder","$url",$file_contents);
        file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);

        $to = "--";
        $subject = "$url down";
        $headers = "From:Deployment Monitor <-->" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $message = file_get_contents('./emailtemplate.html');

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

Depending on how the ping returns the system will show two badges `LIVE` or `DOWN`:

```
if (200==$retcode) {
    echo "<td><span class='badge badge-success'>LIVE</span></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td><span class='badge badge-danger'>DOWN</span></td>";
```

When the ping comes back with `DOWN` an email is sent out automatically as shown in the code above, this works partially, as shown the word `depplaceholder` in `emailtemplate.html` needs to be replaced by `$url` which it does, for the first website is down.

i.e. emails:

email 1: `Title: server 1 down`
         `Body: server 1 down`

email 2: `Title: server 2 down`
         `Body: server 1 down`

email 3: `Title: server 3 down`
         `Body: server 1 down`

for some reason the body doesn't change like the title does, is this because the title is pulled from the same page and not from the `emailtemplate.html`

Comment: So 160 pings and all of them write to the same file?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca when the server is up, the page shows `LIVE`, nothing happens, when the server comes back with `DOWN` the email is sent out, this is not the issue, this works, the issue is that if 5 servers are down, the emails I receive will say `Server 1,2,3,4,5 down` but the email body says `server 1,1,1,1,1 down`.

Comment: Can you please show your template file? Also, what happens when you run this again and you overwrote your template?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Currently the template is very basic, the body is 
`<body> <h1> depplaceholder is down </h1> </body>`
So as said `depplaceholder` returns the value of server 1 to 160 but i.e if server 35 and server 68 are both offline it'll pick up the first server that is showning as down.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv All 160 urls are pulled from a database, this all works fine, they're shown correctly, ping correctly but the email template only picks up the 1st offline deployment and the rest is left out in the body of the template, the header however is showing correctly.

Comment: Ok, then what happens after you overwrite it? Is there something other than this script that regenerates it? Because even if your script worked, the second run would load a template containing `<body> <h1> 1,2,3,4,5 is down </h1> </body>` and couldn't find a `dapplaceholder` to substitute.

Comment: Can you also show us the contents of `emailtemplate.html` too? I think every time a ping completes you overwrite the status of _all_ the servers, not just the one you just pinged, because there does not seem to be any means of identifying which `depplaceholder` corresponding to a server to replace...

Comment: if I replace `depplaceholder` with i.e `egsgfdgfdg` it shows `egsgfdgfdg` on all emails, no this is the only thing running 

`$path_to_file = './emailtemplate.html';`
`$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);`
`$file_contents = str_replace("depplaceholder","$url",$file_contents);`
`file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);`

pulls the file, checks it and when it finds the `depplaceholder` to change it with `$url`, `$url` contains the url for that server i.e `test.test.com`

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv the `emailtemplate.html` only contains the following: `<body> <h1> depplaceholder is down </h1> </body>`

Comment: @Jeffrey can you please address the point I'm making? What happens on the second run? The file no longer contains a `depplaceholder` string, does it?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, it contains the word I put in there to replace it.

Comment: So how do you expect it to work on the second run?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca for it to show test? (word I replaced it with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since comments are too limited I'm writing a full answer.

Suppose, as you say in the comments, that your template file is as follows:

```
<body> <h1> depplaceholder is down </h1> </body>
```

So you open that file (called `./emailtemplate.html`), read its content and put it inside the `$file_contents` variable.

At this point you replace `dapplaceholder` inside that variable with the content of `$url`.

```
$file_contents = str_replace("depplaceholder", $url, $file_contents);
```

Then you **overwrite** `emailtemplate.html` with

```
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

At this point you send the email with the content of `emailtemplate.html` as its body.

Then you ping another server and you load your template, which, at this point (since you overwrote it) contains

```
<body> <h1> 1 is down </h1> </body>
```

You try

```
$file_contents = str_replace("depplaceholder", $url, $file_contents);
```

But there's no `dapplaceholder` in your file anymore! So this line actually does nothing! And you end up with your mails containing

```
<body> <h1> 1 is down </h1> </body>
```

Forever and ever.

I hope my point is clear now.

**EDIT:**

As for how to solve this. Unless you have a requirement to keep the email texts (in which case I suggest you save the information to a database instead) you have to realize that you don't actually need to save anything to the filesystem.

So just lose this line

```
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file_contents);
```

And change the part where you set the message to

```
$message = $file_contents;
```

Problem solved!

Comment: I understand what you mean, because for email 1 the `depplaceholder` is being replaced by `$url` so when email 2 is being generated `depplaceholder` no longer exists and therefor uses the `$url` from email 1 once more.

Comment: @Jeffrey I also added a solution, if you need it.